# public ip of server hosted on aws ebt

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

I'm very new to AWS infrastructure, but due to my task i needed to deploy simple web server on AWS to let mobile developers test API.

This solution, which i deployed used one banking API.
And to use their API i should provide them public IP address.

Would you kindly tell me, how can i get public IP address of server hosted on AWS in elastic beanstalk application?

I could assume that there are a lot of different ip addresses, in EC2, EBT.
But i can't understand which ip address they will see if me server will make http request to their server.

Comment: It's beanstalk as in "a stalk of beans" not "beans talk". It is typically abbreviated EB, not EBT.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've created [single-instance environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html), your EB instance will be provided automatically (you don't have to do anything) with a static public IP address in the form of [elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html). Thus you can provide this address for whitelisting.

If you use [load-balanced environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html), ensuring public static IP address warrants a  procedure that is a bit more complex and requires placing your EB instances in private subnet and setting up [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html). The gateway will have a static public IP, and you can use it for whitelisting.

Comment: yes, i have a classic load balancer, https and configured route53

Comment: @YehorButko Are your EB instances in private subnets behind a NAT?

Comment: i didn't configure it

Comment: i'm very sorry for being so noobish, i understand how it could be annoying, but i'm super new to all this infrastructure :C